# Japanese kinship terms

Tags: kinship-terms

How do I address someone else's great-grandchild/great-grandchildren?
ひいおまごさん or ひおまごさん?

Answer (score 1):

First off, the honorific prefix お or ご must come at the very front of a word.  Neither ひい[お]{●}まごさん or ひ[お]{●}まごさん work because the ひ (*"great-"*) and the noun it modifies cannot have anything between them.  As a (very rough) analogy, it might be like saying *"great mister grandchild"* instead of *"mister great-grandchild"* -- weird enough that listeners / readers might not be able to understand the intended meaning.

*(Note: This works differently for "grandparent" terms, because the お prefix has l̲e̲x̲i̲c̲a̲l̲i̲z̲e̲d̲ for those terms -- it has become part of the regular word.  However, for まご, the お is still a prefix.)*

Separately, I'm more accustomed to the short-"i" version ひまご, but then again my experience with Japanese has been in the Tōhoku and Kantō regions, and the long-"i" version ひいまご might be more common in other parts of Japan.  That said, I do see that a couple of my dictionary resources list ひいまご as an alternative form and point the reader to look at ひまご as the main entry, so take that for what you will.  :)  One such example is [here at Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%9B%BE%E5%AD%AB-2056633#E7.B2.BE.E9.81.B8.E7.89.88.20.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.E8.AA.9E.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8).

Lastly, Google can sometimes be helpful in getting a quick-and-dirty idea of how common different wording might be.  Looking up ["おひまごさん"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%8A%E3%81%B2%E3%81%BE%E3%81%94%E3%81%95%E3%82%93%22) shows me only one hit anywhere at all, while looking up ["ひまごさん"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%B2%E3%81%BE%E3%81%94%E3%81%95%E3%82%93%22) shows me a little more than 1,000 hits.  My guess is that the unprefixed version is used more commonly.

Comment: Re "the honorific prefix お or ご must come at the very front of a word": there seems to be an exception though, 親御さん.

Comment: @EddieKal, looks like the 御【ご】 in that word is actually a suffix, if the [Kotobank entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%A6%AA%E5%BE%A1-455017) is anything to go by.  Seems like it's short for 御前【ごぜん】, which apparently also has use as a suffix.

Comment: This is very interesting. Thanks for the Kotobank entry. I think I will post a separate question about the interesting morphology of that word.